# Hortonworks hiveserver2 jdbc error

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I installed hortonworks, and I tried to access to hiveserver2 by jdbc. But I got error

> ERROR : unsupported hive2 protocol

Code:

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

try {


   Class.forName(driverName);

   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
            System.out.println("error");
   }

java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://192.168.0.96:10000/db","id","pwd");
```

Program versions:

- Hadoop - 2.2.0
- Hive - 0.12.0

Is there any solution for this situation?

Comment: This means that the hive server is using a newer protocol that isn't supported by your client.  What version of the Hive libraries are you including with your client program?

Comment: Currently I use 0.12.0 version. I think something different in Hortonworks. Is someone use Hortonworks HIVE with JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

As referred to by @climbage, there is a mismatch on protocol versions used by your client code and the hive server.

Here is the specific hive source code that is rejecting the request (in [Hive Connection source code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveConnection.java)

private void openSession(Map sessVars) throws SQLException {
    TOpenSessionReq openReq = new TOpenSessionReq();

```
 ..

try {
  TOpenSessionResp openResp = client.OpenSession(openReq);

  // validate connection
  Utils.verifySuccess(openResp.getStatus());
  if (!supportedProtocols.contains(openResp.getServerProtocolVersion())) {
    throw new TException("Unsupported Hive2 protocol");
  }
```

My suggestion:  look at the src/test code in the core-hive module of the specific version of hive that is deployed on your servers. They will have jdbc tests that you can "lift" into your client code.

Also, have you simply tried hive and not hive2?

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://192.168.56.101:10000/default", "root", "");
```